# Populate columns based off person column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, hyperlink, auto-populate

Been searching for a few days and trying multiple suggestions but to no avail. I have a person column to select a user for the data in that line. I want to create a hyperlink to open a document library that is filtered to that member's name (which is also set up with a person column). I've been trying to find a way to calculate or autofill another column or the hyperlink using the person's display name, but I don't know the formulas to use. I also tried autofilling the title or another column based on the person column input, but again, I don't know the right formulas to use, since you can't use a calculated column. I don't mind having two extra hidden columns for first and last name, but I would only use them if they could be autofilled. I also looked into using power automate, but that stuff confuses me. Please help me.

Comment: Are you using standard SharePoint list forms or Power Apps customized list forms?

Comment: Standard. I was hoping to do this without forms or power apps. I know it's difficult, but I'm trying to make it as easy as possible to fix or update when I'm not here anymore.